# SQLite: Convert string to Date

Tags: sqlite, date-formatting

I am trying to convert datetime in string - Dec 11 2017 00:00:00AM to YYYY-MM-DD format in SQLite. The tables were originally in Oracle, so the to_date() was able to convert the text to date. But how do I achieve this in SQLite? The date and strftime functions are unable to take in the month as text for conversions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it through code, like this (DELPHI):

Main proc:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DB: TSQLite3Database;//helper class
  Stmt: TSQLite3Statement;//helper class
begin
  DB := TSQLite3Database.Create;
  DB.Open(ExtractFilepath(application.exename) + 'YourDB.db3');

  // here you set the function that will SQLite use to call in the query
  DB.fnTO_MouliTr_DATE;

  // prepare statement and fire it after 
  Stmt :=  DB.Prepare('update YourTable set NewDate = TO_MouliTr_DATE(NewDate)');

  Stmt.Step;

  Stmt.Free;
end;
```

call to sqlite3_create_function_v2

```
procedure TSQLite3Database.fnTO_MouliTr_DATE;
begin
  sqlite3_create_function_v2(FHandle, 'TO_MouliTr_DATE', 1 , SQLITE_ANY, nil,InternalSQLFunctionTO_MouliTr_DATE,nil,nil, nil);
end;
```

and finaly procedure that will do the work

```
procedure InternalSQLFunctionTO_MouliTr_DATE(ctx: PSQLite3Context; n: Integer; apVal:
    PPSQLite3ValueArray); cdecl;

var StartPos: integer;
  s1: string;
  DT: TDateTime;

begin
  case n of
    1: StartPos := 1;
  else
    begin
      raise ESQLite3Error.Create('The TO_MouliTr_DATE function requires 1 argument.');
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  if (sqlite3_value_type(apVal[0])=SQLITE_NULL) then
    sqlite3_result_text(ctx, PAnsiChar(''), Length(''), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
  else
  begin

    s1 := sqlite3_value_text(apVal[0]);

    // HERE YOUR LOGIC
    DT := StrToDateTime(s1);

    s1 := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', DT);

    sqlite3_result_text(ctx, PAnsiChar(s1), Length(s1), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

  end;
end;
```

unfortunately this one will not finish the work because StrToDateTime cannot convert given string to datetime, but I just wanted to point you to the direction that you should go regarding your question.

Hope this will help